# constructing a lattice in a number field with prescribed localizations

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

For a prime number $p$, we denote the localization of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. Let $k$ be an algebraic number field and denote by $\mathfrak{o}_{k}$ its ring of integers. By a lattice in $k$ we mean an additive subgroup of $k$ which is free of rank $[k:\mathbb{Q}]$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-submodule $M$ of $k$ is called a $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-lattice in $k$ if $M$ has rank $[k:\mathbb{Q}]$ (since $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ is a PID and $M$ is torsion-free, $M$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-module).

According to Theorem 10 in page 99 of S. Lang's book Elliptic Functions, the following is true:
Given for each $p$ a $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-lattice $M_{(p)}$ in $k$ such that $M_{(p)}=\mathfrak{o}_{k,(p)}$ for almost all $p$, there exists a unique lattice $L$ in $k$ such that $L_{(p)}=M_{(p)}$ for all $p$.

I tried to prove this theorem but I couldn't. Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't have time to write out the proof myself right now, but I can tell you that Weil's *Basic Number Theory* has a proof in his chapter on lattices. If you're still having trouble later, I'll write up the details.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I will try to understand the proof in Weil's book.

Comment: I have trouble with proving that $L:=\cap M_{(p)}$ is a lattice in $k$. Can you explain this?

Comment: Third edition, p. 28 states the intersection of two lattices is again a lattice for finite p (finite intersection of compact opens is again compact and open). So you do this for your finitely many exceptions, and the rest fit together already.